# Date-fns date different after format()

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

If I create a date using date-fns `addYears()` I see the date as expected:

```
let d = addYears(new Date('2015-01-01), 1) // 2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

However, when I use `format()` to output as a string, I lose a day:

```
let f = format(d, 'YYYY-MM-DD')

// expected output: 2016-01-01
// actual output: 2015-12-31
```

Is this a bug in `format()` or the expected output? If so, is it possible to workaround this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was just discussing this with someone. If you append `T00:00` (explicitly setting the hours and minutes) to the date string it stores the correct date. If the hours and minutes are omitted the time zone offset, date-times are interpreted as user local time. When you omit the time altogether, dates are interpreted as UTC.

So `foo = new Date('2015-01-01T00:00')` should store the correct date, then use the `format.()` function as you are, it will output the correct date.

```
let d = addYears(new Date("2015-01-01T00:00"), 1);
let f = format(d, "YYYY-MM-DD");

will output ---> 2016-01-01
```